# How to integrate AppLovin SDK in iOS flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, applovin

I was going to integrate applovin sdk to flutter in ios.
when i run 'flutter run' command, it gives this error

> fatal error: 'AppLovin/AppLovin.h' file not found
> #import <AppLovin/AppLovin.h>
> note: did not find header 'AppLovin.h' in framework 'AppLovin'

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to subscribe to their [repository](https://github.com/AppLovin/AppLovin-MAX-Flutter). You should get a notification for the initial release.